# Unable to Model Array of Invariant Polymorphic Classes

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there a way to model this without annotating A<+T>?

```
class A<T> {
  static value: T  
}

declare var Bar: Class<A<string>>
declare var Baz: Class<A<number>>

function foo<T, U: T>(...rest: $ReadOnlyArray<Class<A<U>>>): Array<T> {
  return rest.reduce((init, { value }) => ([ ...init, value ]), [])
}

(foo(Bar, Baz): Array<string | number>)
```

**Error**

```
5: declare var Bar: Class<A<string>>
                            ^ string. This type is incompatible with
6: declare var Baz: Class<A<number>>
                            ^ number
6: declare var Baz: Class<A<number>>
                            ^ number. This type is incompatible with
5: declare var Bar: Class<A<string>>
                            ^ string
```

https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGtCAXMuAlsNAG5ggCuApgFzSLYYC+GGAJtaGAE7Vm9oAIV70AwuCjwEeHoQB2Ac2TIOXcHwE9hYAF7jJEafHmUAtgCNqPFVmz2MAM0rzgRAPbzoj9+6QAaaABVehQACgA6KL48egASACVqMHYAeXkQAE9YHh4wTPgJSCMEIJVkAEp6HLyClHQ7PlxKHi8Y3Ai+dkpgajCwhUJcQLQBKn5mCugAXlQwgG1oKIjB4bGaaABdCsD57ZY7ewcwn3cwkR5AkV0quFz8+FkFRWgAH2hTS2tKoA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on Flow, but I believe you can get this working by changing

```
$ReadOnlyArray<Class<A<U>>>
```

to

```
$ReadOnlyArray<{+value: U}>
```

Comment: I should have made the example simpler. Any idea without using the object literal syntax?

https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwIIB4AqA+eA3gL4BQJoSc8AbrPAEKwBc8AwtKplsgC4wCWAOwDmuXOXDQqtGAygAvFuxTIumQQFcAtgCMQMMSXjGTEyggBmGwWB78A9oPgX79nABp4AVRZ4AFAB0QXC8LAAkAEogUMAA8oIQAJ7oMDBQiZjKnFheYrgAlCwpaRl4RiYVJH4u9n6MMJ6M8oUYqemYvAIi8AA+8Jq6+gVAA

Comment: Definitely hitting the limits of knowledge. I think it's hard to do with classes because `A<string>|A<number>` is not the same as `A<string|number>`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: When you say "not the same," you mean that ```A<string>``` is not a subtype of ```A<string|number>```? Or are you just saying classes are not associative?